# Why do I need to use setters along with a custom constructors?

Tags: java

First of all, excuse me if this is a stupid question but I will give an example for clarification.

```
public class Example{

    private String InstanceVariable1="whatever"; //setting a value for the sake of the example

    Example(){
    }

    Example(String InstanceVariable1) {
        this.InstanceVariable1=InstanceVariable1;
    }
}
```

Why do I need setters here? Doesn't my custom constructor set the value of `InstanceVariable1` to `whatever`?

Comment: What makes you think you *need* setters? You don't

Comment: If you need to change the variable value later, you will need the setter

Comment: "*Why do I need setters here?* - Error 404: Setter not found. --- If you do not intend to change the value  of `InstanceVariable1` after construction, remove the default constructor, remove the initial value of of `InstanceVariable1` and make it `final`. This way, `Example` is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) --- In Java, field names should start with a lowercase character. Thus, `InstanceVariable1` should start with a lowercase character --- Please format your code properly.

Comment: @JBNizet Well what made me think so is the solution of a problem I was solving, they were using a setter and it seemed completely unnecessary to me. I am new to this classes thing so sorry.

Comment: Well, maybe the solution needed that setter to modify the value of the instance variable. Or maybe the class was used in another use-case which needed that setter. Or maybe the person implementing that solution adds setters for each and every instance variable even though it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: It is the last option, it is my instructor and he just was like "Always add setters and getter whatever your solving"

Comment: @Noobdeveloper what you really need is `noobDeveloper.setTeacher(competentTeacher)` :-)

Comment: I agree. We are learning the basis of classes all alone as "I don't have time to explain this to you" he started with composition and inheritance directly (I am paying $2200 for this course)

Comment: There is no setter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, but in designing any system you have to consider what parameters are essential to your class and what parameters are optional, and which of these might need to change over the life time of the class

For things that are mandatory- the class just won't be able to do its job without them - make them parameters of the constructor so that they have to be provided.

For optional things, maybe set a sensible default in the Constructor but let the developer using your class set them later via a setter.

For parameters that will realistically change over the life of the instance - they really will need a setter because you can only invoke the constructor once.

You might choose both constructor and setter for things you expect to be provided but also expect to change, and you might choose constructor only for things that definitely won't change. It's all a mix and balance of what your class needs to start, and needs to work. Strive for the minimum number of constructor parameters necessary

I would additionally point out that you've provided a parameterless constructor. If you don't provide setters but do provide a way for developers to construct your class without providing values, then you can reach a situation where values are never set, nor settable. Consider whether a parameterless constructor is a wise provision

---

For example(s), a Person class might need an indication of Gender - they have a gender from birth, though some people aim to function without one. Consider making gender a construct-time provision. 
A person's job changes a lot and they really don't have one at construction time, or they might never have one. Most people are born without a name and could realistically function without one for a while. A name is officially assigned later and might change through the lifetime of the person. Job and name might make a good candidate for a setter. If you're writing a system that only deals with working age people perhaps Job will be a constructor parameter, though `null` might be a valid value, indicating they don't have one. A person's place of birth is set at construction time and doesn't change over the life of the instance - if it was essential for the class to know the place of birth to even do any part of its work, it may be a good constructor/only option

Comment: Thank you! I have to wait few minutes to accept your answer but this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I need setters here?

You don't.

> Doesn't my custom constructor set the value of InstanceVariable1 to "whatever"?

Yes (because the initializer is relocated to the constructor), and it's also set to the parameter value the constructor receives.

You only need a setter if you want to be able to set the value of an instance variable via a method. The usual reason for that is to set a private instance variable. This class, without any setters, is just fine:

```
class Example {
    private int foo;

    Example(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

Nothing outside `Example` can set `foo`. No setter required, *unless* you want something outside `Example` to be able to set `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If by design all object's fields set by constructor, then these fields could be set as `final`. You don't need setters to set its values. Final object that guarantees, no state change after instantiation is said *immutable*. It is safe to use and share immutable object in multithreaded environment.

```
public final class Example {

    private final String instanceVariable1;//setting a value for the sake of the example

    Example(String instanceVariable1) {
        this.instanceVariable1 = instanceVariable1;
    }

    //All getters
    public String getInstanceVariable(){
        return this.instanceVariable1;
    }
}
```

By providing setter, it means the object state could changed(*mutable*) after its instantiation. When no longer immutable, it need special guard(synchronization) for both read and write on its state. This is true during concurrent access to the same mutable object instance.